# TinyXml to parse conf file

Tags: c++, xml

I`m try to realize how to use TinyXML library.

I have to parse this conf file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<Client>
    <port  num = "20035">
    <server_addr ip="127.0.0.1">    

        <AV_list>
                <AV>
                        <AVNAME>BitDefender</AVNAME>>
                        <AVPATH> C:\Program Files\Common Files\BitDefender\BitDefender Threat Scanner\av64bit_26308\bdc.exe </AVPATH>
                        <AVMASK>0x80000000</AVMASK>
                        <AVCOMMANDLINE> %avpath% \log=%avlog% %scanpath% </AVCOMMANDLINE>
                        <AVREGEX>(%scanpath%.*?)+(([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})+(.+[a-zA-Z_])</AVREGEX>
                        <AVLOG>C:\log\bd_log.txt</AVLOG>
                </AV>
        </AV_list>  
</Client>
```

And c++ code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "tinyxml.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    TiXmlDocument doc( "D:\\client_conf.xml" );
    bool loadOkay = doc.LoadFile();
    if ( loadOkay )  
        printf("Yes \n");
    else
        printf("No \n");

    TiXmlHandle hDoc(&doc);
    TiXmlElement* pElem;
    TiXmlText* pText;
    TiXmlHandle hRoot(0);
    pElem = hDoc.FirstChildElement().Element();    
    if (!pElem)
     printf("error element");

    hRoot = TiXmlHandle(pElem);
    pElem = hRoot.FirstChild("server_addr").Element();
    const char* info = pElem->Attribute("ip");
    printf(  "%s \n", info);    

    pElem = hRoot.FirstChild("port").Element();
    info = pElem->Attribute("num");
    printf( "%s \n", info); 

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Now I can get first two param, but dont figure out how to reach "AV_list" block. Any help will be appreciated. (:

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the TinyXml Documentation. Your friend is the [TiXmlNode Class Reference](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlNode.html). You may use most of the Node functions also on TiXmlElements. 
You already use the FirstChild() function to get the first child of an element; use the NextSibling() function to iterate over all elements. You can also use the NextSiblingElement() function to get the element directly.

Antother more sophisticated solution would be to use XPath to retrieve elements from the xml file. There is [TinyXPath](http://tinyxpath.sourceforge.net/) that builds on top of TinyXML. It needs some [knowledge of XPath](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html) but it might be worth it. ([XPath standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/))